# How to hide iPad keyboard in Safari + designMode=on

Tags: ipad, safari, ios5, designmode

iOS5 now supports designMode=On. I set that on a document of an iframe and it works pretty well. Now I want to hide the onscreen keyboard with Javascript after clicking on an image inside that editable document (=iframedoc in my case). 
I tried  iframedoc.blur(), iframedoc.activeElement.blur(),iframedoc.body.blur() or iframe.contentWindow.blur() and I also tried to set the focus to a hidden link or a submit button but it is not working for me.

For text input fields just blur seems to work but I have a designmode=on document so the solutions for this question are not working for me:
[iPad Safari - Make keyboard disappear](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5937339/ipad-safari-make-keyboard-disappear)

Answer (score 3):

Call `preventDefault()` in the event handler for the `'touchstart'` event.

Answer (score 1):

it seems that after hours I found a workaround: 
1. set focus to another standard input field on screen so the keyboard is connected to that field
2. make a blur() of that field

this workaround is a bit complicated to handle because it scrolls the view to that other field. So that has to be solved as well like with a moving input field.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a [great solution](http://uihacker.blogspot.com/2011/10/javascript-hide-ios-soft-keyboard.html?codekitCB=411883007.969147) found from this [stack answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5937339/ipad-safari-make-keyboard-disappear?codekitCB=411882206.129468), I was stuck on this too.