# OnKeyboard Hide in Sencha Touch

Tags: javascript, android, iphone, sencha-touch, extjs

I need to know is there any function in sencha touch to know if the keyboard hides. I want to call a function when a keyboard hides.

Any Idea...

Comment: you wanna know for android,iphone both..or is that me who don't getting what `Sencha` is?

Comment: sencha can be used for most of the mobile platform. That's why i tagged iphone and android

Comment: Okay,Thanks for the reply now the rest about Sencha, I will google it.

Answer (score 0):

Pls check the below link.  Hope this helps....

[iPad Safari - Make keyboard disappear](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5937339/ipad-safari-make-keyboard-disappear)

To prevent showing the keyboard on:

```
<input type="text" name="someInput" />
```

for when you want to do something like use a jQuery UI datepicker...

add a readonly attribute like so:

`<input type="text" name="someInput" readonly="readonly" />`

If you are trying to be mindful of people with JS turned off, you could always leave off the attribute and add it in your code:

```
$('[name=someInput]').attr('readonly','readonly');
```

Comment: i am doing it in sencha touch. Pblm is when i load my sencha pag, tab bar goes off the screen and address bar appearing in the screen. for that i tried a code. it's working but i want to put this code in keyboard hide event.

Comment: i don't want blur. because in android, there is a keyboard hide button. if the user tap on that button, keyboard hides but focus will remain