# UIAutomation [UITextField resignFirstResponder]

Tags: javascript, ios, unit-testing, automated-tests, ui-automation

How can I get the keyboard dismissed when using UI Automation tests?
I've been looking at [UIAElement](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/ToolsLanguages/Reference/UIAElementClassReference/UIAElement/UIAElement.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40009903) and [UIATextField](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/ToolsLanguages/Reference/UIATextFieldClassReference/UIATextField/UIATextField.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40009925) documentation but couldn't find something that suggests so.

```
var textField = toolbar.textFields()[0];
var textView = toolbar.textViews()[0];
function testFeature1() {
    if (textField.hasKeyboardFocus() || textView.hasKeyboardFocus()) {
        // Resign first responder .. How?
    }
    // Do my tests
}
```

Comment: javascript code in iOS ?

Comment: yes. I started to write Automation tests and they all are in javascript :)

Comment: On a Java Script context, try this =>
 http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5937339/ipad-safari-make-keyboard-disappear

Comment: Javascript is the language but unfortunately UIAutomation is not related with HTML or DOM things at all. `blur()` Didn't work :(

Answer (score 2):

Quite an old question but I had to deal with that right now.
This command worked perfectly :

```
target.frontMostApp().keyboard().typeString("\n");
```

Answer (score 1):

From UIAutomation, you don't really have access to the internals to do things like resign first responder--UIAutomation is just like a regular user of your app. Could you do:

`app.keyboard().buttons()["return"].tap();` ?