# JQuery Mobile: how to disable default keyboard when clicking in text field?

Tags: jquery-mobile, keyboard, textinput

I am currently using input text fields that spawn a chooser (listview with various entries) when they are clicked on.  Testing this on the appMobi emulator works flawlessly; however, when testing it on an iPhone, the default keyboard appears when the text fields are touched and then quickly disappears to be replaced by the chooser.

Is there a way I can prevent the default keyboard from showing with JQM?

Comment: You might give this a try:
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5937339/ipad-safari-make-keyboard-disappear

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion.  Unfortunately, I can't have the fields be read-only and they should also be able to capture user input.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If they require user input, then you can't prevent the browsers' default implementation (at least in a x-browser friendly way). They is certainly no solution with JQM.

I suggest you style your own text box from a div or similar, using html/css. With js you can then wire up the chooser to this element.