# Date and Time Picker plugin for jQueryMobile not working in Android Emulator

Tags: jquery-mobile, android-emulator

I am newbie to JQueryMobile,
When I test at [my jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/mapsv3/k5c96/) its work fine, but when i run at
Android Emulator, it become like this [image](https://docs.google.com/open?id=0B5dnb9JhVY-8aV9uT3lZN1Jrdlk). The date and time picker is missing

Below is my sample code,

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <meta charset="utf-8" />
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1" />
        <title></title>
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://ajax.aspnetcdn.com/ajax/jquery.mobile/1.1.1/jquery.mobile-1.1.1.min.css" />
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="resources/css/my.css" />
                
        <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="http://code.jquery.com/mobile/latest/jquery.mobile.min.css" />
        <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="http://dev.jtsage.com/cdn/datebox/latest/jqm-datebox.min.css" />

        <script type="text/javascript" src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.7.1.min.js"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="http://code.jquery.com/mobile/latest/jquery.mobile.min.js"></script>

        <!-- Optional Mousewheel support: http://brandonaaron.net/code/mousewheel/docs -->
        <script type="text/javascript" src="resources/js/jquery.mousewheel.min.js"></script>

        <script type="text/javascript" src="http://dev.jtsage.com/cdn/datebox/latest/jqm-datebox.core.min.js"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="http://dev.jtsage.com/cdn/datebox/latest/jqm-datebox.mode.calbox.min.js"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="http://dev.jtsage.com/cdn/datebox/latest/jqm-datebox.mode.datebox.min.js"></script>
        
        <script type="text/javascript" src="http://dev.jtsage.com/cdn/datebox/i18n/jquery.mobile.datebox.i18n.en_US.utf8.js"></script>
        
        
        <style>
            /* App custom styles */
        </style>
        <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.7.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
        <script src="https://ajax.aspnetcdn.com/ajax/jquery.mobile/1.1.1/jquery.mobile-1.1.1.min.js"></script>
        <script src="resources/js/my.js"></script>
    </head>
    <body>
        <!-- Home -->
        <div data-role="page" id="page1">
            <div data-theme="b" data-role="header">
                <a data-role="button" data-inline="true" data-transition="slide" data-theme="b" href="#page1" class="ui-btn-left">
                    Calendar
                </a>
                <a data-role="button" data-inline="true" data-transition="slide" href="#page1" class="ui-btn-right">
                    Save
                </a>
                <h4>
                    Edit Event
                </h4>
            </div>
            <div data-role="content">
                <div data-role="fieldcontain">
                        <label for="txtTitle">
                            Title
                        </label>
                        <input name="" id="txtTitle" placeholder="" value="" type="text" />                    
                </div>
                
                <div data-role="fieldcontain">
                  <label for="link1">Start Time*</label>
                  <input name="link1" type="text" data-role="datebox" data-options='{"mode": "timebox"}' id="link1" />
                  <label for="link3">End Time*</label>
                  <input name="link3" type="text" data-role="datebox" data-options='{"mode": "timebox"}' id="link3" />
                  <label for="mydate">Date*</label>
                  <input name="mydate" id="mydate" type="date" data-role="datebox" data-options='{"mode": "calbox"}'>
                </div>
                
            </div>
        </div>
        <script>
            //App custom javascript
        </script>
    </body>
</html>​
```

Appreciate anyone can guide me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

this seems to be a problem with the emulator, I just tested your example on my device (HTC Desire with Android 2.2) and it works fine, see screenshot 
[image]

the only issue is, the keyboard also opens after pressing one of the icons... but that's another issue...[image]

and concerning the keyboard issue, you might want to take a look at [these answers](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5937339/ipad-safari-make-keyboard-disappear)

Comment: Hi Taifun, thats weird, I tested with my nexus 7 and the result is still same, the date and time picker is missing