# Dismiss iOS Keyboard on website

Tags: ios, html, web

I want to dismiss the iOS keyboard when the user hits the return key on the virtual keyboard my (HTML/CSS/JS based) website. Is this possible?

The current form looks like:

```
<input type="email" class="form-control" placeholder="Enter Email"
    id="email-form" autocorrect="off" autocapitalize="off">
```

thanks

Comment: possible duplicate of [iPad Safari - Make keyboard disappear](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5937339/ipad-safari-make-keyboard-disappear)

Answer (score -1):

[Dismiss iOS Keyboard on website](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25208913/dismiss-ios-keyboard-on-website)

The keyboard dismissal is disabled when you present your UIWebView using a modal ViewController with presentation style UIModalPresentationFormSheet!
You have to override your ViewController’s disablesAutomaticKeyboardDismissal method:

```
    - (BOOL)disablesAutomaticKeyboardDismissal {
return NO;
```

}

Comment: He isn't talking about iOS programming. He is talking about web.